# In Chrome Only, Button "Title" Tooltip Has Split-Second Redraw Problem

Tags: html, google-chrome

I noticed a Chrome-only problem:

If I have Buttons with "Title" attributes, and I sequentially hover over each one, the Title Tooltip has a visible split-second redraw.

If you are in Chrome (mine is *Windows,  71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (32-bit)*)

1) Hover over the 1st button - no issues,

2) Then, hover over the other buttons - you can see the rectangle gets resized and quickly re-adjusted. It's very quick, but a flash is visible. I don't know what the old box is that gets replaced, but I assume it's the previous one that you viewed.

No such problem exists in Firefox. Each new "Title" tooltip is a brand-new window without any redraws.

```html
<button id="buttonAddEventItemBottom" class="btn btn-primary addEventButton" title="Add Activity">Add Activity</button>
<button id="buttonEditSaveEventItemBottom" class="btn btn-primary editDeleteEventButton" title="Update Activity">Update Activity</button>
<button id="buttonEditDeleteEventItemBottom" class="btn btn-primary editDeleteEventButton" title="Delete Activity">Delete Activity</button>
<button id="buttonCancelAdd" class="btn btn-primary addEventButton" title="Cancel Activity">Cancel</button>
```